# Dynamic Table generation inside the while loop including phpexcel

Tags: php, loops, mysqli, while-loop, phpexcel

Here is my While loop, I totally have 5 Records matching for the result, so I am using the while loop to handle this,

As I am doing it in phpexcel, I am handling this in the following way.

The Head will be having upto `A7` column, so I will be starting from `A8`,

And I will be having `A8-A20` for one set, as given in the below screenshot

[image]

So As i am proceeding with loop, The First Entry will have from `A8-A20`, Then `A22-A34`, A36-A48 (Each Entry will have 2 columns in between).

For that i am declaring `$flag_head` as 8 before the loop starts and adding `14` as the at the loop ends, . (As the initial step i am giving colour the the First Row or entry so that it will keep on printing the coloured column for `n` number of entry)

But I am stuck up with the initial thing, when I execute it is always printing only at A8 column though it has many entries. What is the point I am missing?

```
$loopquery = "SELECT * FROM prsprimary_details where PrsdkID = '11'";

if ($loopresult = $mysqli->query($loopquery)) 
{
  $flag_head=8;
  while ($row = $loopresult->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    cellColor('A'.$flag_head, 'ccccff');
    cellColor('B'.$flag_head, 'ccccff');
    cellColor('C'.$flag_head, 'ccccff');
    cellColor('D'.$flag_head, 'ccccff');
    cellColor('E'.$flag_head, 'ccccff');
    cellColor('F'.$flag_head, 'ccccff');
    cellColor('G'.$flag_head, 'ccccff');
    cellColor('H'.$flag_head, 'ccccff');
    cellColor('I'.$flag_head, 'ccccff');
    cellColor('J'.$flag_head, 'ccccff');
    cellColor('K'.$flag_head, 'ccccff');
    cellColor('L'.$flag_head, 'ccccff');
    $flag_head+14;
}
}
```

Comment: Can i we see more code, because i think your missing stuff. i expect something like $obj->cellColor('L'.$flag_head, 'ccccff'); i don't see an instance of your phpexcel class.

Comment: sorry, but what is the last line of code: $flag_head+14; ? should it be: $flag_head++; ?

Comment: Should be as simple as `$flag_head += 14;`

Comment: @MarkBaker : Exactly $flag_head += 14; is the need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Small change in your code makes the sense as @MarkBaker suggested.

You have `$flag_head+14;` It means at the end of the the loop it will add 14 to the `$flag_head` but not assigning it to any variable. But if you do `$flag_head += 14;` or some thing like `$flag_head = $flag_head + 14;` .  I recommend `$flag_head += 14;` That will add the 14 to the `$flag_head` so on the next loop it will add another `14` and it goes on until the loop ends.

So, The thing you need to do is to change the `$flag_head+14;`  to `$flag_head += 14;`

Hope it helps you.